# Creating Method of Arrays Using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'd like to create a method where it can print out an array created by user's input in Scanner.
The data type of the array is double. 
So far, I have created an array of the size that the user has provided, but how do I enter all the double input elements into an array then print it out in a method? 
Do I need to ask the user to give each number one by one? I would like to avoid this. Thanks

Comment: Please show us some code you've written, especially how the user enters the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you don't want hundreds of alert messages asking the user for input, correct? Just ask once?

If that is the case, you can ask the user to separate the input with some symbol. For example a semi-colon. Then the user can input something like this:

```
1;2;3;4;5
```

Then what you do is split the input to get the array, and you print it out using a for loop and a printing method of your choice (e.g. system.out or show in an alert message)

Hope that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could grab user input from the console, and have them separate entries with spaces... ie:

```
Enter your series separated by spaces:
123.33 333.44 342.22 43.33
```

Storing this result to a String and then passing it to this method.

```
    public double[] setDoubleArray(String input, int arraySize) {

         double[] doubleArray = new double[arraySize];
         Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

         for (int i = 0; s.hasNextDouble(); i++) {
             doubleArray[i] = s.nextDouble();
         }

         s.close();

         return doubleArray;
    }
```

Is this what your looking for?